# Why does my delegate called from backgroundworker runs in main thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker, system.timers.timer

I am writing a program that will allow me to run a number of different hardware test routines.

The routines can be quite time consuming, lasting up to 30mins. During this time, I have to control a selection of test equipment to set up conditions and take measurements.

I was thinking that using a background worker to carry out the tasks would be ideal, and allow the UI to stay responsive. This worked well until one of the routines requires me to take measurements every 1.5seconds. I am using a system timer to trigger these events. The timer is created and started in the doWork sub of the background worker, however, I find that the delegate is running in the main(UI) thread and not in the background worker thread as I thought.

Am I doing something wrong? I have attached the main parts of a simplified program that has the same structure.

```
  Private Sub getMeasurement()
    ' Runs in backgroundWorker thread
    Me.TextBox2.Text = (System.DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds.ToString
    startTime = System.DateTime.Now
    Debug.Print("Thread name is " & Thread.CurrentThread.Name & ", ID = " & Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
End Sub

 Private Sub OnTimedEvent()
    'Runs in own thread, Calls getMeasurement which runs in BackgroundWorker thread
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "OTE"
    Debug.Print("In OnTimedEvent, thread = " & Thread.CurrentThread.Name & ", ID = " & Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    Dim ServiceTimerDelegate As New ServiceTimerDelegate(AddressOf getMeasurement)
    Me.BeginInvoke(ServiceTimerDelegate)
End Sub

  Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "BW1"
    mTimer = New Timers.Timer(1490) ' 14.9secs (allow for some latency)
    AddHandler mTimer.Elapsed, New Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf OnTimedEvent)
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim i As Integer

    'main timer for measurements every 1.5secs (may change to take interval from UI)
    Select Case e.Argument
        Case "Sunday"

            mTimer.Start()
            Debug.Print("Thread in DoWork = " & Thread.CurrentThread.Name & ", ID = " & Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)

            startTime = System.DateTime.Now

            'main loop for temperature ramping
            For i = 20 To 70
                If (worker.CancellationPending = True) Then
                    e.Cancel = True
                Else
                    Thread.Sleep(500)
                    worker.ReportProgress((i - 19) * (100 / 50))
                    i += 1

                End If

            Next
        Case Else
            e.Cancel = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What makes you say the DoWork event is running in the UI thread?

Comment: If `getMeasurement()` is running in a thread, then this line: `Me.TextBox2.Text = (System.DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds.ToString` should be failing as you are trying to update the UI in a thread that is not the UI thread.  You don't, by any chance, have `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` disabled do you?

Comment: This is all entirely normal, you are using the form's BeginInvoke() method to run getMeasurement().  Which is *required*, you cannot update UI from a worker thread.  The System.Timers.Timer does nothing useful, you might as well use a winforms timer.  Much the same for the BackgroundWorker, it does nothing but sleep.

Comment: In trying to keep things as simple as possible, I seem to have caused confusion. Let me try to rectify this.

Comment: The code I posted is not my code, but it does have the same basic structure. It is also not complete. I have a UI that calls RunWorkerAsync that in turn leads to DoWork. I have test routines working with the backgroundworker and everything is good. I report progress and update the UI through the ReportProgress sub that runs in the UI thread. When the routines are complete, the background thread finishes as expected.

Comment: I know that trying to update the UI from the background thread should give me an exception, but for some reason it doesn't. Anyway, if you can ignore that line for now, it shouldn't really be there

Comment: My problem is that I have a test routine that ramps the temperature of the DUT up and down a couple of times, which takes a fair amount of time. During this ramp sequence, I need to accurately take measurements every 1.5 seconds. So I thought I would use a timer. I chose a system timer as it is meant to have a higher priority.

Comment: When I introduce the timer into doWork, as can be seen in the code. The debug.print statement tells me that I'm in the backgroundworker thread. Then when the timer event fires, this is handled by a different thread, which is normal. But, when the delegate is run, it is being run in the UI thread. I expected and want it to run in the backgroundworker thread.

Comment: By the way, the comments in some of the subs such as 'Runs in background thread, are were I expected them to run, not where they are actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Three things are confusing here, and make me think that the code you've posted above doesn't actually use the BackgroundWorker for its function.

1. The DoWork event always runs in a separate thread from the UI. That's the entire point of it. ReportProgress runs in the UI thread, but you're not making use of that.
2. You don't actually appear to be running the BackgroundWorker at all in the above code. Rather, you seem to be using a ServiceTimerDelegate - not 100% sure I know what that is. You've defined a BackgroundWorker within your DoWork handler (which makes no sense), but you never seem to be actually hooking a BackgroundWorker up to that handler nor calling RunWorkerAsync on it.
3. Even if you were running getMeasurement() in a BackgroundWorker, it should fail - you're altering the contents of a UI item, which should cause an exception due to InvalidCrossThreadAccess. If you need to alter a UI control, use the ReportProgress event, which occurs within the UI thread.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @roryap "You're not running your code in a BackgroundWorker" isn't an answer for why code isn't executing the way he expected it to within a BackgroundWorker? I mean, if I'm wrong about that fact, yeah, it's a *bad* answer, but this seems like a significant part of his confusion.

Comment: @roryap By all means, if you've got any better idea of what the issue above is, please enlighten both of us, because I'm honestly curious about what he's trying to do. This is the best I've got, and it's severely compromised by the fact that the only thing he actually seems to be running (ServiceTimerDelegate) seems to be an object he's created himself - this question is the only reference Google has to it.

Comment: Please see comments that I have added in the previous answer